# How to calculate and autofill values, based on variables from multiple sub() modules?

Tags: excel, vba

First of all I would like to thank everyone in advance for their their invaluable advice - I have learned a lot from this forum, even tho that I havent contributed by myself yet

I'm self-taught user and I have to work hard to make my (simple) scripts to work, however recently I have hit hard dead-end and have no clue how to continue

I have multiple tables that are pulled from an external file (so Im working with variable size of these tables) and my final goal is to create a new table that would calc (and autofill the formulas into columns and rows as long as there is data to support it) following from the pulled tables

And to be honest I didnt come / found any solution to this, I cant solve the problem that green lines on which my calculations should be based of are

- a) variable (rows)
- b) comes from three different modules (because of how I have
  writen the script)

Green rows are summed in code

Blue fields should be desired result

- mGain should be in my case on the picture `(G16-F16)+(G21-G8)`
- mKum is `IFERROR(G25/G16;0)`
- mKum % is m.Kum in percentages `IFERROR(G25/G16;0)`
- mPerform is `(G16+G21/F16+G8)-1`
- yPerform is `G27+H27+I27+J27` (sum Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4 for the given year)

[image]

I have added picture to maybe explain a little bit better my intensions + I didnt copy whole code, just part for the first table - rest of the modules are just the same but with different destination cells (and Im aware that this solution is probably very very clumsy, but sadly my best solution)

I hope that i expressed my issue at least a little bit clear, once again thanks in advance for your tips!
Rae :(

```
 Sub Main()
 
 Clear
 ActualValue
 MathActualValue
 AddedValue
 MathAddedValue
 Flow
 MathFlow
 RemoveEmptyRows
    
  End Sub

 Sub Clear()
 
 Worksheets("IN7").Range("E1:ZZ999").Clear
 
 End Sub
 Sub ActualValue()
  
 Dim datarng As Range
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim en_likematch As Boolean
    Dim Result As Long
    
    Dim cust As String    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    'Sheets("IN7").activate
    Range("E4:AZ" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    
    cust = Sheets("IN7").Range("Customer").Value
    en_likematch = Sheets("IN7").Range("likeMatch").Value
    
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="", ReadOnly:=True)
    
    wb.Activate
    Sheets("Act_value").Select
    Sheets("Act_value").AutoFilterMode = False
    
    lr = Sheets("Act_value").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set datarng = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AZ$" & lr)
    
    If cust <> "" Then
        If en_likematch = True Then
        datarng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & cust & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
        Else
        datarng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & cust
        End If
    End If
    
    Result = Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
    
    If Result > 1 Then
        Range("A1:AZ" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Sheets("IN7").Select
        
        Range("E4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        
        Range("A1").Select
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
      
      
         Set rng = Range("E4:ZZ4")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(222, 244, 180)
        cell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 15, 20)
        
        Else
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    End If
Next

    Set datarng = Nothing
    wb.Close False
    Set wb = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

Sub MathActualValue()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim lr As Long
    lr = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Cells(1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

    Dim lc As Long
    lc = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Cells(1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious, False).Column

    Dim fcrng As Range: Set fcrng = ws.Range("F2", ws.Cells(lr, "F"))
    Dim lkrow As String: lkrow = fcrng.Address(, 0)
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = ws.Cells(lr + 1, "F")
    Dim ColCount As Long: ColCount = lc - cell.Column + 1

    Dim rowrng As Range: Set rowrng = cell.Resize(, ColCount)

    rowrng.Formula = "=SUM(" & lkrow & ")"

For Each cell In rowrng
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(155, 244, 180)
        cell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 15, 20)
        cell.Font.Bold = True
        
        Else
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    End If
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Haven't looked in details, but at a glance it seems you are looking for `Function`, return values, and passing procedure parameters around. By parameterizing your code you could probably delete the other similar modules that are affecting other ranges.